# VC++ 2010 debugger shows too many files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-c++

I've finally converted my project over to VC++ 2010 from 2008 and what a headache the debugger is giving me.  When I step through with F11, the debugger sends me on a wild goose chase through every little line of code of xlock.cpp, xmtx.c, new.cpp, dbgmalloc.c and even .asm files.  This is really making it a pain to get right to the code I want.  Is there anyway to not show so much code when debugging?  I never had such an issue with 2008.  I've poked around Google for about an hour now, not really even sure what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage this with the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\NativeDE\StepOver` registry setting. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx) or [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/visual-studio-msvc-debugging-NoStepInto.html) for examples.